# Speed of image file reading in python

Tags: imagej

I'm reading lots of 16MB tiff files into a numpy array, then into a python Queue (that never fills) from an external USB disk drive.

iotop in Linux reports file reading speed of around 11-12MB/s.

If I use ImageJ(a Java application) to read the same files, I get speeds of around 26MB/s.

This is the snippet that does the reading: It runs on a separate single thread to the rest of the application.

```
def fileReader(self):
    for file_ in self.files:
    im_array = np.asarray(Image.open(file_))
    self.im_array_queue.put(im_array)
```

I'm wondering whether the lower speed is due to a Python IO limitation or whether it's the creation of the array.

Answer (score 2):

Ive found tifffile to be excellent for loading tiffs, comparable to imagej: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/code/tifffile.py.html
It also supports 16bit and multipage tiffs

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Python limitation.

Using openCV

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread(file_)
```

I get speeds up to 26MB/s comparable with ImageJ